# Unable to integrate Google Maps on IBM Worklight

Tags: html, google-maps, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I have trying a lot of ways to try showing an inch of google maps on my applications screen but nothing seems to work until now

MY HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>GoogleMaps</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/GoogleMaps.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCC_qKehMg7x4nlda1vtoXlAPwYTmCgbs0&sensor=false"></script>    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        </head>
        <body id="content" style="display: none;">
             <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" id="content">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%"></div>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

My JS:

```
function wlCommonInit(){


}

$(document).on('pageinit', '#index',function(e,data){    
       // This is the minimum zoom level that we'll allow
       var minZoomLevel = 12;

       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          zoom: minZoomLevel,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       });

      /* // Bounds for North America
       var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
         new google.maps.LatLng(28.70, -127.50), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(48.85, -55.90)
       );

       // Listen for the dragend event
       google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
         if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

         // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

         var c = map.getCenter(),
             x = c.lng(),
             y = c.lat(),
             maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
             maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
             minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
             minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

         if (x < minX) x = minX;
         if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
         if (y < minY) y = minY;
         if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

         map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
       });

       // Limit the zoom level
       google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
         if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
       });  */

    });
```

My CSS:

```
/* Reset CSS */
a, abbr, address, article, aside, audio, b, blockquote, body, canvas, caption, cite, code, dd, del, details, dfn, dialog, div, dl, dt, em, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, html, i, iframe, img, ins, kbd, label, legend, li, mark, menu, nav, object, ol, p, pre, q, samp, section, small, span, strong, sub, summary, sup, table, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, time, tr, ul, var, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Worklight container div */
#content {
    height: 460px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 320px;
}

#content {
    padding: 0;
    position : absolute !important; 
    top : 40px !important;  
    right : 0; 
    bottom : 40px !important;  
    left : 0 !important;     
}
```

I tried another way to check whether my api key was working or not http://jsfiddle.net/wrkf8/3/  it was working and when I copy pasted the same exact code it never worked on worklight. I even tried to use [this](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/w/list) but no use, everything works fine when ran stand alone on a browser but when it is brought it into the work light environment its goes blank. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are quite a few existing questions about Google Maps integration with Worklight; have you looked at them? See this query: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bworklight%5D+google+maps+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Also, there's a Hello Maps blog post out there that walks you through it. The post is a year old, so it's for an older version of Worklight. You might have to adapt. You didn't mention which version of Worklight you are running.   https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/dhuyvett/entry/using_google_maps_in_worklight_hello_map15?lang=en

Comment: @Barbara I have seen the tutorial already and that used dojo kit but what I want something done using jQueryMobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of issues here.
First off, you are using a really old version of jQuery mobile.  Depending on what version of Worklight you are using, it may not be compatible with the jQuery that Worklight is providing.  If you are on WL 6, you should be using jQM 1.3.  Next, you are including jQM before you include jQuery.  If you use the Worklight new project wizard, and add jQM in the wizard, everything will be added to the html in the right order.  I don't see the JavaScript being included in the html.  In fact the standard 3 js files (initOptions, project name and messages) don't seem to be there either.  Your content div has the same id as body ("content") and this is a magic ID that is causing display to be set as none.  the id on the content div needs to be removed or changed.

Create a new Worklight app and use the wizard to include an up to date jQuery Mobile  (1.3.1 for WL6.0, 1.3.1 or 1.3.2 for WL 6.1) and most of this will be straightened out.  Then you will find that the map is still not visible because it has a height of 0px.  You need to add map_canvas to your css rule:

```
#content, #map_canvas {
padding: 0;
position : absolute !important; 
top : 40px !important;  
right : 0; 
bottom : 40px !important;  
left : 0 !important;     
}
```

That still isn't quite right. The bottom of the map is cut off by the footer.  For a sample of a Worklight App using jQuery Mobile and google maps, see: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/dhuyvett/entry/including_external_content_in_a_worklight_application1?lang=en  That app isn't focused on mapping, but the jQuery equivalent to the dojo mapping widget in the other blog posts is included in the attached app.

IMPORTANT: the project attached to that blog post was written in WL 5.  If you want it to work in WL 6, you will need to update the jQuery Mobile.